# python: instantiating and accesing method of other class at runtime

Tags: python

I have a requirement for my project like this:

There are three modules, lets say first, second and third.

The third module has more than one class.

The second module calls methods of one of the classes defined in third module and it should know the class name after reading the config file. (Though below working code is not reading through config file)

First module calls methods of second module which in turn call methods defined in class of third module. In short, second module works as plugin.

I have written a working code like this:

**First Module:**

```
from secondclass import secondClass


class firstClass():
  def __init__(self):
    print self

  def call_second(self):
    secondClass.call_third_class(secondClass())


obj = firstClass()
obj.call_second()
```

**Second Module**

```
def _get_driver():
  module = __import__("thirdclass")
  driver = getattr(module, "thirdClass")()
  return driver


class secondClass(object):

  def __init__(self):
    self.driver = _get_driver()

  def call_third_class(self):
    res = self.driver.sum(20, 30)
    print "res :", res
```

**Third Module**

```
class thirdClass():
  def __init__(self):
    pass

  def sum(self, number1, number2):
    return number1 + number2


class fourthClass():
  def __init__(self):
    pass

  def multiply(self, number1, number2):
    return number1 * number2
```

Since I am new to python I don't know whether this is the correct way(pythonic way) to do it. Is there be a better way(I know , there is always a better way)?

Comment: I think it's a good method.